# Is it possible for individuals or companies to hire an EEA citizen to be a trustee to obtain a .it domain?

Tags: domain-registration, domain-registrar, cctld

As we understand it, .it domains require trustees if an individual or company is not EU based.

We have found a variety of .it domain trustee services on the web. It is challenging to get a sense of which of these companies are businesses that will stay in business, are reliable, and trustable.

On the other hand, we have colleagues and friends in the EU who we would trust to become trustees for our domain for our company's work. Could they serve as a trustee? Reading the restrictions, we don't see an explicit mention of [this approach](https://payments.google.com/payments/apis-secure/u/0/get_legal_document?ldi=329784).

Is it possible for individuals or companies to simply hire one of these people as a trustee and list their contact information as the whois contact for the domain for a .it domain?

Do we need to transfer the control of the domain to the trustee as well - or is keeping control of our domain registrar account okay in this circumstance?

(For example, as an aside and along those lines, we are wondering how reddit.com did it with redd.it which refers back to the .com.)

Comment: Keep in mind that Google only shows sites on most country code domains in the search results for that country itself.   If you plan on doing something "creative" (like redd.it), then your site won't show up in Google search outside Italy.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen anything on the official registry websites that addresses the issue explicitly. Some TLDs explicitly prohibit the practice and also the leasing of domain names to third parties (I seem to remember .ca is an example).

From their [website](https://www.nic.it/en/find-your-it/faq):

> The registration of a domain name in the ccTLD .it is permitted only
> to persons who have citizenship, residence or a registered office in
> the countries of the European Economic Area (EEA), the Vatican, the
> Republic of San Marino, and Switzerland.

So it looks like you can, and you will be fine probably. But whoever is listed as registrant will be considered the legal owner and responsible for the domain name, regardless of whether you have the actual control. I am not a lawyer but I understand this means legal responsibility if your company is embroiled in some kind of trouble relating to the use or misuse of the domain name (this is stretch, but signing anything on behalf of another party always needs consideration).

That also means that in case of a dispute (commercial or otherwise) the domain name could be held hostage. Such a situation is not uncommon when a webmaster registers a domain name in their own name rather than their client's. Then you also have to consider what would happen if the person was to disappear or die in an accident. If nobody else has access to the control panel, this could be a problem.

I think a number of registrars do provide the service, this could be a better option than relying on a single person.